# Django Custom Manager Method that returns object when asked by value

Tags: python, django, syntax

I'm trying to make a method for a model "Clase" that returns a "Clase" whose "codigo" value matches an argument. So far i have this:

```
class CodigoClaseManager(models.Manager):
"""
Custom manager that enables geting a Clase by codigo
"""
def get_by_code(self, code):
    return super(CodigoClaseManager,self).get_query_set().filter(codigo=code)

class Clase(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    byCode = CodigoClaseManager

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'clases'
```

My problem is that, when i try to call this get_by_value method, it always tells me that the argument "self" is missing.

```
>>> Clase.byCode.get_by_code(code="1234")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get_by_code() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Am I taking a wrong aproach or is it an error in my code? I have recently started learning django and would very much apreciate help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should construct a `CodigoClaseManager` object, so *call* the constructor:

```
class Clase(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    byCode = CodigoClaseManager()  # 🖘 call the constructor
    
    # …
```

Your manager also contains an error: it is `get_queryset`, not `get_query_set`, so:

```
class CodigoClaseManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_code(self, code):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(codigo=code)
```

furthermore if you want to use the `.objects` manager as well, you need to include that explicitly since Django includes only `.objects` if there is no other manager defined. So in that case you use:

```
class Clase(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    byCode = CodigoClaseManager()
    objects = models.Manager()  # 🖘 objects manager
    
    # …
```

Comment: Now i have two different issues. One, the model `Clase` doesn't have the `objects` attribute anymore (so now i can't do `Clase.objects.all()`). And two, now it throws this error: `'super' object has no attribute 'get_query_set'`. I'm starting to think my aproach is wrong.

Comment: @Bito: it is `get_queryset` in your `super()` call, and if you want to use `objects` you will need that manager explicitly, so `objects = models.Manager()` since Django does not include that one if you included another manager.

Comment: @Bito: see edit.